# flutter TextField with auto textDirection

Tags: flutter, textfield, direction

I want to use **TextField** in the Flutter to enter **two languages** *(one of them is RTL and the other is LTR)* so that one language is entered in each line.
How can this be done so that the **textDirection** display that line correctly in TextField?
This is done properly in WhatsApp and messaging applications.
How can I do this in the flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use any text editor plugin e.g: [flutter_quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill), [html_editor_enhanced](https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced), [fleather](https://pub.dev/packages/fleather), .. .
I used fleather and I think it's the best Flutter text editor
you can use the editor area only without the editor bar, and this is the samble code to use it:

```
import 'package:fleather/fleather.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlexibleDir extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlexibleDir({super.key});
  @override
  State<FlexibleDir> createState() => _FlexibleDirState();
}

class _FlexibleDirState extends State<FlexibleDir> {
  FleatherController? _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (mounted) {
      _controller = FleatherController();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (!mounted) _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  String get text => _controller!.plainTextEditingValue.text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Multi direction field',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 80,
              width: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.yellow[300],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
              child: FleatherEditor(
                controller: _controller!,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: preview]